# SourceTree shows all files as Unstaged under ".vs" folder of a Visual Studio Project

Tags: git, visual-studio, atlassian-sourcetree

SourceTree shows all files as Unstaged under ".vs" folder of a Visual Studio Project as you see below:

[image: Unstaged Files???]

Please note that: The weird thing is other team members have same git ignore and they don't see these files.

How can we change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your .gitignore file to exclude the .vs directory.

**Example:**

```
# Exclude all .vs folder variations
**/.vs/
```

Comment: Thanks @nbstrat It did not work. 
The weird thing is My team members have same git ignore and they don't see these files.

Comment: Have you previously committed those files to your local repository?  Once a file has been committed to your local repository, it will continue to be tracked.

Comment: No, never comitted them before. While commiting them in VS I can not see them as "To be Commit" Just in SourceTree. May it be some kind of Cache problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You should gitignore them. You can use this.

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

Comment: The weird thing is other team members have same git ignore and they don't see these files. Than ks Deniz Tasdogen